# I'm getting an error when I use size(vec) to find size of a vector instead of vec.size(). How to fix this?

Tags: c++, vector

The error that is being generated is below.

```
error: 'size' was not declared in this scope
```

When I use nums.size(), it is working fine. It could be because of using an older compiler version, but in my system when I check the version it shows 10.3.0, which I think is the latest version. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is wrong with `nums.size()`?

Comment: @DanielLangr It is good and I used it till now, but size(nums) looks more good.

Comment: @GowthamVurimi `std::size` was introduced by C++17. You may need to enable its support (`-std=c++17` or something like that).

Comment: @GowthamVurimi Did you include the header <iterator>?

Comment: @DanielLangr How do I enable its support? I'm already using the latest version of g++.

Comment: @GowthamVurimi Add `-std=c++17` (or `-std=c++20`) command line argument to your `g++` call.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn't until now, but even after doing so, it is giving the same error.

Comment: @DanielLangr It is working now. Thank you. But is there any other way to get around this since I mostly run code using VS code and it auto-generates the command to execute?

Comment: You say that the version of your compiler is 10.3.0. But *which compiler* is that the version of? There are many possible compilers.

Comment: @GowthamVurimi I don't use VS code, but I guess there are ways how to choose a C++ version. Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is the output I get when I execute g++ --version in cmd.

`g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: @DanielLangr I didn't. I'll check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::size` function was added in C++17, therefore, you need to enable its support. With GCC, just add `-std=c++17` as a command-line argument to your `g++` call.

You can also check the libstdc++ source code: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/range_access.h#L236. As you can see, there is an `#ifdef` that makes `std::size` available only if C++17 (or higher standard) support is applied.